# how to format multiple files via multithreading

Tags: multithreading

I'm using multiplethreading to change the case of multiple text files and comparing the time required according to the number of threads i use. I'm not able to understand how to select a set of files for processing

Answer (score 0):

What I do (I have done this using c/c++, Java, and python):

1. create a queue with enough space to hold all of the filenames
2. put all of the filenames in the queue
3. create and start the number of threads you want
4. each thread needs to know where the queue is
5. a thread tries to get a filename from the queue
6. if the queue is empty the thread exits
7. otherwise the thread processes the file then go to step 5
8. Wait for threads to finish
9. that’s it

Comment: @archit The scheme I outlined works fine only because each thread is doing the same thing with data they get from the common queue, and each thread terminates itself after processing a file and there no more files to work on. If your case is more complicated then look into ThreadPoolExecutor. It is good to learn about it anyway because in the future you are probably going to need it.